# show message when incorrect login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, error-handling

I have tried this code

When i login with incorrect username and password then it redirect to webform2.aspx where i want to show message **Wrong username and password**

how i do that ?

i am trying below code but it is not working

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(loginmethod(txt_us.Text,txt_pwd.Text)!="NA")
        {
            FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
            String strRole =Assignroles(txt_us.Text);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txt_us.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, strRole, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
            FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)));
            loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
            Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = ("Incorrect UserName/Password");
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }
        txt_us.Text = "";
        txt_pwd.Text = "";
    }
    private string loginmethod(string UserName, string Password)
    {
       try
       {
           login_class lg_class = new login_class();
           Entities2 login = new Entities2();
           string logn = Convert.ToString(lg_class.loginfu(UserName, Password).Rows[0]["id"]);
           Session["ID"] = logn.ToString();
           return (logn);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           return (ex.Message.ToString());

       }

    }
```

loginfu method

```
  public DataTable loginfunction(string username,string password)
        {
            try
            {
                Entities2 lg = new Entities2();
               List<SP_GetLogin_Result> gr = lg.SP_GetLogin(username, password).ToList();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
                foreach (var l in gr)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(l.id);
                }
                return dt;   
            }

           catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception();

            }

        }
```

**UPDATE**

I do this but this show error

```
 Entities2 lg = new Entities2();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt=lg.SP_GetLogin(username,password).ToList();
        if (dt.Rows.Count== 0)
        {
            return "NA";
        }
        else
        {
            return dt.Rows[0].ID.ToString();
        }
```

'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: Debug and Check What loginmethod return when you enter wrong username and password.

Comment: exception occur at catch of login method .. There is no row at position 0.  @HrkPatel

Comment: please show us your loginfu method.
Or you can check if no row then method will return "NA"

Comment: @HrkPatel check update

Comment: it looks like you are returning only ID from database. Right?

Comment: yes @HrkPatel.......

Comment: Then you can avoid use of Datatable, instead of Datatable use string and return it. and if there is no data then return NA.

Comment: NA means there is text with NA in in id and password in database

Comment: i  replace datatable and use string now how i return this show error on return dt? @HrkPatel

Comment: See when you try with wrong username and password, that time database will return nothing. so now you check if there is no value coming from database then method will return NA and if there is some value then return that value.

Comment: this is what i am asking i am trying that but not works.. and also i  do that on button click

Comment: @HrkPatel check update

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 Entities2 lg = new Entities2();
               List<SP_GetLogin_Result> gr = lg.SP_GetLogin(username, password).ToList();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
                foreach (var l in gr)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(l.id);


          }
```

by

```
Entities2 lg = new Entities2();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = lg.SP_GetLogin(username, password);
    if(dt.rows.count == 0)
    {
    return "NA";
    }
    else
    {
    return dt.rows[0].something. tostring();
    }
```

try this

Comment: but in this how i execute foreach loop and this show error... i try this  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = w.SP_GetLogin(username, password);
            if(dt.Rows.Count==0)
            {
                return "NA";

            }
            else
            {
                return dt.Rows[0].Tables[0]["id"];
            }

Comment: something what?

Comment: something means what you are returning from database

Comment: i am returning id

Comment: something means what you returning, it has column name